# Svg symbol is not fully displaying in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, sprite

My code is like this:

```html
<div>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><symbol viewBox="0 0 152 45" id="icon-google-play"><title>icon-google-play</title><defs><linearGradient x1="91.503%" y1="4.965%" x2="-38.331%" y2="71.904%" id="dxa"><stop stop-color="#00A0FF" offset="0%"/><stop stop-color="#00A1FF" offset=".66%"/><stop stop-color="#00BEFF" offset="26.01%"/><stop stop-color="#00D2FF" offset="51.22%"/><stop stop-color="#00DFFF" offset="76.04%"/><stop stop-color="#00E3FF" offset="100%"/></linearGradient><linearGradient x1="107.584%" y1="49.999%" x2="-130.469%" y2="49.999%" id="dxb"><stop stop-color="#FFE000" offset="0%"/><stop stop-color="#FFBD00" offset="40.87%"/><stop stop-color="#FFA500" offset="77.54%"/><stop stop-color="#FF9C00" offset="100%"/></linearGradient><linearGradient x1="86.247%" y1="17.846%" x2="-50.137%" y2="194.808%" id="dxc"><stop stop-color="#FF3A44" offset="0%"/><stop stop-color="#C31162" offset="100%"/></linearGradient><linearGradient x1="-18.81%" y1="-54.156%" x2="42.095%" y2="24.867%" id="dxd"><stop stop-color="#32A071" offset="0%"/><stop stop-color="#2DA771" offset="6.85%"/><stop stop-color="#15CF74" offset="47.62%"/><stop stop-color="#06E775" offset="80.09%"/><stop stop-color="#00F076" offset="100%"/></linearGradient></defs><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M146.25 45H5.625C2.53 45 0 42.47 0 39.375V5.625C0 2.53 2.53 0 5.625 0H146.25c3.094 0 5.625 2.53 5.625 5.625v33.75c0 3.094-2.53 5.625-5.625 5.625z" fill="#000"/><path d="M146.25.9a4.73 4.73 0 0 1 4.725 4.725v33.75a4.73 4.73 0 0 1-4.725 4.725H5.625A4.73 4.73 0 0 1 .9 39.375V5.625A4.73 4.73 0 0 1 5.625.9H146.25zm0-.9H5.625C2.53 0 0 2.53 0 5.625v33.75C0 42.47 2.53 45 5.625 45H146.25c3.094 0 5.625-2.53 5.625-5.625V5.625c0-3.094-2.53-5.625-5.625-5.625z" fill="#A6A6A6"/><path d="M76.653 24.47c-2.646 0-4.803 2.013-4.803 4.786 0 2.755 2.157 4.784 4.803 4.784s4.803-2.03 4.803-4.784c0-2.773-2.157-4.785-4.803-4.785zm0 7.685c-1.45 0-2.7-1.196-2.7-2.9 0-1.723 1.25-2.9 2.7-2.9 1.45 0 2.7 1.177 2.7 2.9 0 1.704-1.25 2.9-2.7 2.9zM66.175 24.47c-2.646 0-4.803 2.013-4.803 4.786 0 2.755 2.157 4.784 4.803 4.784s4.802-2.03 4.802-4.784c0-2.773-2.155-4.785-4.802-4.785zm0 7.685c-1.45 0-2.7-1.196-2.7-2.9 0-1.723 1.25-2.9 2.7-2.9 1.45 0 2.7 1.177 2.7 2.9 0 1.704-1.25 2.9-2.7 2.9zM53.712 25.94v2.03h4.858c-.145 1.14-.526 1.974-1.106 2.555-.707.706-1.813 1.486-3.752 1.486-2.99 0-5.328-2.41-5.328-5.4s2.338-5.4 5.328-5.4c1.613-.002 2.79.633 3.66 1.45l1.433-1.433c-1.214-1.16-2.827-2.048-5.093-2.048-4.096 0-7.54 3.334-7.54 7.43s3.444 7.43 7.54 7.43c2.212 0 3.88-.724 5.184-2.084 1.34-1.34 1.758-3.227 1.758-4.75 0-.47-.036-.906-.11-1.268h-6.832zm50.97 1.575c-.397-1.07-1.612-3.044-4.095-3.044-2.465 0-4.512 1.94-4.512 4.786 0 2.682 2.03 4.784 4.75 4.784 2.19 0 3.46-1.34 3.986-2.12l-1.63-1.088c-.544.797-1.288 1.323-2.356 1.323-1.07 0-1.83-.49-2.32-1.45l6.398-2.646-.22-.545zM98.16 29.11c-.055-1.848 1.43-2.79 2.5-2.79.833 0 1.54.417 1.776 1.014l-4.278 1.776zm-5.202 4.64h2.102V19.686h-2.102V33.75zm-3.445-8.21h-.072c-.47-.562-1.376-1.07-2.518-1.07-2.393 0-4.585 2.103-4.585 4.803 0 2.68 2.192 4.766 4.585 4.766 1.142 0 2.047-.508 2.52-1.09h.07v.69c0 1.83-.978 2.81-2.555 2.81-1.287 0-2.085-.926-2.41-1.704l-1.83.76c.524 1.27 1.92 2.828 4.24 2.828 2.465 0 4.55-1.45 4.55-4.983v-8.59h-1.994v.78zm-2.41 6.615c-1.45 0-2.664-1.214-2.664-2.883 0-1.685 1.213-2.918 2.663-2.918 1.432 0 2.556 1.233 2.556 2.92-.002 1.667-1.125 2.88-2.557 2.88zm27.43-12.47h-5.03V33.75h2.097v-5.328h2.932c2.326 0 4.613-1.684 4.613-4.367s-2.287-4.37-4.613-4.37zm.053 6.78H111.6v-4.82h2.986c1.57 0 2.46 1.298 2.46 2.41 0 1.09-.89 2.41-2.46 2.41zm12.973-2.02c-1.52 0-3.094.67-3.746 2.153l1.864.78c.398-.78 1.14-1.033 1.918-1.033 1.086 0 2.19.652 2.208 1.81v.144c-.38-.218-1.195-.544-2.19-.544-2.008 0-4.053 1.104-4.053 3.167 0 1.882 1.648 3.094 3.493 3.094 1.412 0 2.19-.634 2.678-1.375h.073v1.085h2.026v-5.392c0-2.497-1.864-3.89-4.27-3.89zm-.254 7.708c-.687 0-1.647-.345-1.647-1.195 0-1.086 1.194-1.502 2.224-1.502.923 0 1.357.2 1.92.47a2.545 2.545 0 0 1-2.498 2.227zm11.905-7.4l-2.406 6.097h-.072l-2.496-6.098h-2.26l3.744 8.522-2.135 4.74h2.19l5.77-13.262h-2.334zm-18.907 8.997h2.1V19.686h-2.1V33.75z" fill="#FFF"/><g transform="translate(10.125 7.875)"><path d="M1.614.605c-.327.347-.52.885-.52 1.58v24.88c0 .7.193 1.235.52 1.582l.084.08L15.635 14.79v-.328L1.698.522l-.084.083z" fill="url(#dxa)"/><path d="M20.282 19.438l-4.646-4.648v-.328l4.647-4.646.104.06 5.505 3.127c1.573.893 1.573 2.354 0 3.25l-5.505 3.126-.105.058z" fill="url(#dxb)"/><path d="M20.387 19.378l-4.752-4.752-14.02 14.02c.518.55 1.373.617 2.337.07l16.435-9.338" fill="url(#dxc)"/><path d="M20.387 9.874L3.953.537C2.99-.01 2.133.057 1.616.605l14.02 14.02 4.75-4.75z" fill="url(#dxd)"/><g transform="translate(0 19.125)" fill="#000"><path d="M20.283.148L3.953 9.427c-.913.52-1.73.485-2.254.013l-.086.083.084.08c.524.474 1.34.508 2.254-.01L20.386.252 20.283.15z" opacity=".2"/><path d="M1.614 9.358c-.327-.347-.52-.885-.52-1.58v.163c0 .698.193 1.235.52 1.582l.085-.084-.086-.08z" opacity=".12"/></g><path d="M25.892 16.086l-5.61 3.188.105.104 5.505-3.127c.786-.446 1.18-1.034 1.18-1.623-.067.532-.468 1.054-1.18 1.46z" opacity=".12" fill="#000"/><path d="M3.953.7l21.94 12.466c.712.405 1.11.927 1.178 1.46 0-.588-.392-1.178-1.178-1.624L3.952.537c-1.57-.894-2.857-.152-2.857 1.65v.164C1.095.55 2.38-.19 3.953.7z" opacity=".25" fill="#FFF"/></g><g transform="translate(46.125 6.75)" fill="#FFF"><path d="M6.56 1.012H1.83v3.452c.01 1.156-.254 1.987-.788 2.47h-.73V9.42h1.055V7.988h4.895V9.42h1.055V6.932h-.754v-5.92H6.56zM5.47 2.067v4.865H2.372c.376-.648.562-1.478.55-2.47V2.067h2.546zM11.49.862c-1.013 0-1.873.355-2.554 1.057-.68.7-1.026 1.566-1.026 2.58s.345 1.88 1.026 2.58c.68.702 1.54 1.057 2.555 1.057 1.014 0 1.875-.355 2.557-1.056.68-.7 1.026-1.57 1.026-2.58 0-1.007-.347-1.873-1.03-2.577-.686-.705-1.545-1.06-2.552-1.06zM13.963 4.5c0 .75-.24 1.376-.717 1.86a2.375 2.375 0 0 1-1.754.724 2.38 2.38 0 0 1-1.753-.725c-.476-.484-.717-1.11-.717-1.86 0-.752.24-1.376.717-1.858a2.38 2.38 0 0 1 1.754-.726c.69 0 1.28.244 1.755.726.477.482.717 1.108.717 1.858zM21.317 6.14c-.547.626-1.218.943-1.99.943-.703 0-1.302-.24-1.784-.712-.48-.47-.725-1.1-.725-1.87s.244-1.4.725-1.87c.482-.473 1.08-.713 1.783-.713.753 0 1.355.274 1.788.816l.078.096.77-.745-.07-.08C21.236 1.246 20.373.86 19.325.86c-1.02 0-1.886.35-2.578 1.042-.69.69-1.042 1.563-1.042 2.596 0 1.033.35 1.907 1.042 2.596.69.69 1.558 1.042 2.578 1.042.562 0 1.088-.113 1.565-.335.478-.222.882-.53 1.2-.91l.067-.08-.76-.76-.08.088zM22.646 2.067h1.886v5.92h1.092v-5.92h1.886V1.012h-4.864v1.055zM30.683 4.756l-1.61-3.744h-1.268l2.324 5.1-.225.492c-.087.188-.177.318-.27.383-.09.064-.225.097-.402.097a.785.785 0 0 1-.397-.108l-.125-.07-.29 1.034.09.038c.253.106.492.16.714.16.743 0 1.306-.428 1.676-1.272l2.626-5.853H32.26l-1.577 3.744zM34.222 7.987h1.092v-5.92h2.924v5.92h1.092V1.013h-5.108v6.974zM44.893 3.906h-3.15V1.012h-1.09v6.975h1.09V4.942h3.15v3.045h1.093V1.013h-1.093v2.893zM50.464.862c-1.014 0-1.873.355-2.555 1.057-.68.7-1.026 1.566-1.026 2.58s.346 1.88 1.026 2.58c.68.702 1.54 1.057 2.555 1.057 1.015 0 1.874-.355 2.555-1.056.68-.7 1.026-1.57 1.026-2.58 0-1.007-.346-1.873-1.03-2.577-.685-.705-1.544-1.06-2.552-1.06zm0 6.22a2.383 2.383 0 0 1-1.754-.725c-.476-.482-.718-1.107-.718-1.858 0-.753.242-1.377.718-1.86a2.38 2.38 0 0 1 1.754-.725c.69 0 1.28.244 1.754.725.477.484.72 1.11.72 1.86s-.243 1.376-.72 1.86a2.376 2.376 0 0 1-1.754.723zM61.868 4.922a1.813 1.813 0 0 0-.68-.546c.212-.128.39-.296.53-.5.178-.262.268-.57.268-.913 0-.558-.208-1.028-.616-1.398a2.104 2.104 0 0 0-1.448-.552h-2.554v6.974h2.686c.58 0 1.09-.193 1.513-.575.43-.385.645-.877.645-1.46 0-.388-.115-.734-.344-1.03zm-1.242-1.304c-.175.194-.406.288-.704.288H58.46v-1.84h1.5c.284 0 .503.094.675.284.175.194.26.4.26.632 0 .23-.09.44-.27.636zm.476 2.314c0 .25-.092.476-.282.69a.92.92 0 0 1-.727.31H58.46v-1.99h1.595c.316 0 .563.1.757.307.195.21.29.434.29.682z"/></g></g></symbol></svg>
</div>

<svg class="icon-google-play" role="img">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-google-play"/>
</svg>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qhsphtfs/

Expected: http://joxi.ru/Dr83MQlTYBMEA6

Actual: http://joxi.ru/LmGyMklS56lGAl

In Google Chrome, Safari works good (green icon on left is displayed), but in Firefox it's not work. What's problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox does not support linearGradients within a symbol tag. The workaround is simple though, move the gradients outside the symbol tag.

```html
<div>
    <svg><defs><linearGradient x1="91.503%" y1="4.965%" x2="-38.331%" y2="71.904%" id="dxa"><stop stop-color="#00A0FF" offset="0%"/><stop stop-color="#00A1FF" offset=".66%"/><stop stop-color="#00BEFF" offset="26.01%"/><stop stop-color="#00D2FF" offset="51.22%"/><stop stop-color="#00DFFF" offset="76.04%"/><stop stop-color="#00E3FF" offset="100%"/></linearGradient><linearGradient x1="107.584%" y1="49.999%" x2="-130.469%" y2="49.999%" id="dxb"><stop stop-color="#FFE000" offset="0%"/><stop stop-color="#FFBD00" offset="40.87%"/><stop stop-color="#FFA500" offset="77.54%"/><stop stop-color="#FF9C00" offset="100%"/></linearGradient><linearGradient x1="86.247%" y1="17.846%" x2="-50.137%" y2="194.808%" id="dxc"><stop stop-color="#FF3A44" offset="0%"/><stop stop-color="#C31162" offset="100%"/></linearGradient><linearGradient x1="-18.81%" y1="-54.156%" x2="42.095%" y2="24.867%" id="dxd"><stop stop-color="#32A071" offset="0%"/><stop stop-color="#2DA771" offset="6.85%"/><stop stop-color="#15CF74" offset="47.62%"/><stop stop-color="#06E775" offset="80.09%"/><stop stop-color="#00F076" offset="100%"/></linearGradient></defs><symbol viewBox="0 0 152 45" id="icon-google-play"><title>icon-google-play</title><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M146.25 45H5.625C2.53 45 0 42.47 0 39.375V5.625C0 2.53 2.53 0 5.625 0H146.25c3.094 0 5.625 2.53 5.625 5.625v33.75c0 3.094-2.53 5.625-5.625 5.625z" fill="#000"/><path d="M146.25.9a4.73 4.73 0 0 1 4.725 4.725v33.75a4.73 4.73 0 0 1-4.725 4.725H5.625A4.73 4.73 0 0 1 .9 39.375V5.625A4.73 4.73 0 0 1 5.625.9H146.25zm0-.9H5.625C2.53 0 0 2.53 0 5.625v33.75C0 42.47 2.53 45 5.625 45H146.25c3.094 0 5.625-2.53 5.625-5.625V5.625c0-3.094-2.53-5.625-5.625-5.625z" fill="#A6A6A6"/><path d="M76.653 24.47c-2.646 0-4.803 2.013-4.803 4.786 0 2.755 2.157 4.784 4.803 4.784s4.803-2.03 4.803-4.784c0-2.773-2.157-4.785-4.803-4.785zm0 7.685c-1.45 0-2.7-1.196-2.7-2.9 0-1.723 1.25-2.9 2.7-2.9 1.45 0 2.7 1.177 2.7 2.9 0 1.704-1.25 2.9-2.7 2.9zM66.175 24.47c-2.646 0-4.803 2.013-4.803 4.786 0 2.755 2.157 4.784 4.803 4.784s4.802-2.03 4.802-4.784c0-2.773-2.155-4.785-4.802-4.785zm0 7.685c-1.45 0-2.7-1.196-2.7-2.9 0-1.723 1.25-2.9 2.7-2.9 1.45 0 2.7 1.177 2.7 2.9 0 1.704-1.25 2.9-2.7 2.9zM53.712 25.94v2.03h4.858c-.145 1.14-.526 1.974-1.106 2.555-.707.706-1.813 1.486-3.752 1.486-2.99 0-5.328-2.41-5.328-5.4s2.338-5.4 5.328-5.4c1.613-.002 2.79.633 3.66 1.45l1.433-1.433c-1.214-1.16-2.827-2.048-5.093-2.048-4.096 0-7.54 3.334-7.54 7.43s3.444 7.43 7.54 7.43c2.212 0 3.88-.724 5.184-2.084 1.34-1.34 1.758-3.227 1.758-4.75 0-.47-.036-.906-.11-1.268h-6.832zm50.97 1.575c-.397-1.07-1.612-3.044-4.095-3.044-2.465 0-4.512 1.94-4.512 4.786 0 2.682 2.03 4.784 4.75 4.784 2.19 0 3.46-1.34 3.986-2.12l-1.63-1.088c-.544.797-1.288 1.323-2.356 1.323-1.07 0-1.83-.49-2.32-1.45l6.398-2.646-.22-.545zM98.16 29.11c-.055-1.848 1.43-2.79 2.5-2.79.833 0 1.54.417 1.776 1.014l-4.278 1.776zm-5.202 4.64h2.102V19.686h-2.102V33.75zm-3.445-8.21h-.072c-.47-.562-1.376-1.07-2.518-1.07-2.393 0-4.585 2.103-4.585 4.803 0 2.68 2.192 4.766 4.585 4.766 1.142 0 2.047-.508 2.52-1.09h.07v.69c0 1.83-.978 2.81-2.555 2.81-1.287 0-2.085-.926-2.41-1.704l-1.83.76c.524 1.27 1.92 2.828 4.24 2.828 2.465 0 4.55-1.45 4.55-4.983v-8.59h-1.994v.78zm-2.41 6.615c-1.45 0-2.664-1.214-2.664-2.883 0-1.685 1.213-2.918 2.663-2.918 1.432 0 2.556 1.233 2.556 2.92-.002 1.667-1.125 2.88-2.557 2.88zm27.43-12.47h-5.03V33.75h2.097v-5.328h2.932c2.326 0 4.613-1.684 4.613-4.367s-2.287-4.37-4.613-4.37zm.053 6.78H111.6v-4.82h2.986c1.57 0 2.46 1.298 2.46 2.41 0 1.09-.89 2.41-2.46 2.41zm12.973-2.02c-1.52 0-3.094.67-3.746 2.153l1.864.78c.398-.78 1.14-1.033 1.918-1.033 1.086 0 2.19.652 2.208 1.81v.144c-.38-.218-1.195-.544-2.19-.544-2.008 0-4.053 1.104-4.053 3.167 0 1.882 1.648 3.094 3.493 3.094 1.412 0 2.19-.634 2.678-1.375h.073v1.085h2.026v-5.392c0-2.497-1.864-3.89-4.27-3.89zm-.254 7.708c-.687 0-1.647-.345-1.647-1.195 0-1.086 1.194-1.502 2.224-1.502.923 0 1.357.2 1.92.47a2.545 2.545 0 0 1-2.498 2.227zm11.905-7.4l-2.406 6.097h-.072l-2.496-6.098h-2.26l3.744 8.522-2.135 4.74h2.19l5.77-13.262h-2.334zm-18.907 8.997h2.1V19.686h-2.1V33.75z" fill="#FFF"/><g transform="translate(10.125 7.875)"><path d="M1.614.605c-.327.347-.52.885-.52 1.58v24.88c0 .7.193 1.235.52 1.582l.084.08L15.635 14.79v-.328L1.698.522l-.084.083z" fill="url(#dxa)"/><path d="M20.282 19.438l-4.646-4.648v-.328l4.647-4.646.104.06 5.505 3.127c1.573.893 1.573 2.354 0 3.25l-5.505 3.126-.105.058z" fill="url(#dxb)"/><path d="M20.387 19.378l-4.752-4.752-14.02 14.02c.518.55 1.373.617 2.337.07l16.435-9.338" fill="url(#dxc)"/><path d="M20.387 9.874L3.953.537C2.99-.01 2.133.057 1.616.605l14.02 14.02 4.75-4.75z" fill="url(#dxd)"/><g transform="translate(0 19.125)" fill="#000"><path d="M20.283.148L3.953 9.427c-.913.52-1.73.485-2.254.013l-.086.083.084.08c.524.474 1.34.508 2.254-.01L20.386.252 20.283.15z" opacity=".2"/><path d="M1.614 9.358c-.327-.347-.52-.885-.52-1.58v.163c0 .698.193 1.235.52 1.582l.085-.084-.086-.08z" opacity=".12"/></g><path d="M25.892 16.086l-5.61 3.188.105.104 5.505-3.127c.786-.446 1.18-1.034 1.18-1.623-.067.532-.468 1.054-1.18 1.46z" opacity=".12" fill="#000"/><path d="M3.953.7l21.94 12.466c.712.405 1.11.927 1.178 1.46 0-.588-.392-1.178-1.178-1.624L3.952.537c-1.57-.894-2.857-.152-2.857 1.65v.164C1.095.55 2.38-.19 3.953.7z" opacity=".25" fill="#FFF"/></g><g transform="translate(46.125 6.75)" fill="#FFF"><path d="M6.56 1.012H1.83v3.452c.01 1.156-.254 1.987-.788 2.47h-.73V9.42h1.055V7.988h4.895V9.42h1.055V6.932h-.754v-5.92H6.56zM5.47 2.067v4.865H2.372c.376-.648.562-1.478.55-2.47V2.067h2.546zM11.49.862c-1.013 0-1.873.355-2.554 1.057-.68.7-1.026 1.566-1.026 2.58s.345 1.88 1.026 2.58c.68.702 1.54 1.057 2.555 1.057 1.014 0 1.875-.355 2.557-1.056.68-.7 1.026-1.57 1.026-2.58 0-1.007-.347-1.873-1.03-2.577-.686-.705-1.545-1.06-2.552-1.06zM13.963 4.5c0 .75-.24 1.376-.717 1.86a2.375 2.375 0 0 1-1.754.724 2.38 2.38 0 0 1-1.753-.725c-.476-.484-.717-1.11-.717-1.86 0-.752.24-1.376.717-1.858a2.38 2.38 0 0 1 1.754-.726c.69 0 1.28.244 1.755.726.477.482.717 1.108.717 1.858zM21.317 6.14c-.547.626-1.218.943-1.99.943-.703 0-1.302-.24-1.784-.712-.48-.47-.725-1.1-.725-1.87s.244-1.4.725-1.87c.482-.473 1.08-.713 1.783-.713.753 0 1.355.274 1.788.816l.078.096.77-.745-.07-.08C21.236 1.246 20.373.86 19.325.86c-1.02 0-1.886.35-2.578 1.042-.69.69-1.042 1.563-1.042 2.596 0 1.033.35 1.907 1.042 2.596.69.69 1.558 1.042 2.578 1.042.562 0 1.088-.113 1.565-.335.478-.222.882-.53 1.2-.91l.067-.08-.76-.76-.08.088zM22.646 2.067h1.886v5.92h1.092v-5.92h1.886V1.012h-4.864v1.055zM30.683 4.756l-1.61-3.744h-1.268l2.324 5.1-.225.492c-.087.188-.177.318-.27.383-.09.064-.225.097-.402.097a.785.785 0 0 1-.397-.108l-.125-.07-.29 1.034.09.038c.253.106.492.16.714.16.743 0 1.306-.428 1.676-1.272l2.626-5.853H32.26l-1.577 3.744zM34.222 7.987h1.092v-5.92h2.924v5.92h1.092V1.013h-5.108v6.974zM44.893 3.906h-3.15V1.012h-1.09v6.975h1.09V4.942h3.15v3.045h1.093V1.013h-1.093v2.893zM50.464.862c-1.014 0-1.873.355-2.555 1.057-.68.7-1.026 1.566-1.026 2.58s.346 1.88 1.026 2.58c.68.702 1.54 1.057 2.555 1.057 1.015 0 1.874-.355 2.555-1.056.68-.7 1.026-1.57 1.026-2.58 0-1.007-.346-1.873-1.03-2.577-.685-.705-1.544-1.06-2.552-1.06zm0 6.22a2.383 2.383 0 0 1-1.754-.725c-.476-.482-.718-1.107-.718-1.858 0-.753.242-1.377.718-1.86a2.38 2.38 0 0 1 1.754-.725c.69 0 1.28.244 1.754.725.477.484.72 1.11.72 1.86s-.243 1.376-.72 1.86a2.376 2.376 0 0 1-1.754.723zM61.868 4.922a1.813 1.813 0 0 0-.68-.546c.212-.128.39-.296.53-.5.178-.262.268-.57.268-.913 0-.558-.208-1.028-.616-1.398a2.104 2.104 0 0 0-1.448-.552h-2.554v6.974h2.686c.58 0 1.09-.193 1.513-.575.43-.385.645-.877.645-1.46 0-.388-.115-.734-.344-1.03zm-1.242-1.304c-.175.194-.406.288-.704.288H58.46v-1.84h1.5c.284 0 .503.094.675.284.175.194.26.4.26.632 0 .23-.09.44-.27.636zm.476 2.314c0 .25-.092.476-.282.69a.92.92 0 0 1-.727.31H58.46v-1.99h1.595c.316 0 .563.1.757.307.195.21.29.434.29.682z"/></g></g></symbol></svg>
</div>

<svg class="icon-google-play" role="img">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-google-play"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert! Works perfectly!